# Pythonic and efficient usage of logical and membership operators

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way to check if some words in combination using logical operators (`or`,`and`) exist in a list of strings ?

Say you have a list of strings:

```
list_of_str = ['some phrase with word1','another phrase','other phrase with word2']
```

I have two cases 1), and 2) where I would like to get the strings that contain or do not contain some words. however I would prefer not to repeat as I do now `if 'word1' not in i and 'word2' not in i and 'word3' not in i`

I would like to get 1)

```
list_1 = [i for i in list_of_str if 'word1' not in i and 'word2' not in i and 'word3' not in i]
output: ['another phrase']
```

and 2)

```
list_2 = [i for i in list_of_str if 'word1' in i or 'word2' in i or 'word3' in i]
output: ['some phrase with word1', 'other phrase with word2']
```

I did find that I can do this for 2), but couldn't use the `all` for case 1)

```
list_2 = [i for i in list_of_str if any(word in ['word1','word2','word3'] for word in i.split())]
output: ['some phrase with word1', 'other phrase with word2']
```

Also is this the most efficient way of doing things ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word23']

list_1 = [i for i in list_of_str if all(w not in i for w in words)]

list_2 = [i for i in list_of_str if any(w in i for w in words)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good use-case for regex alternation, if efficiency matters:

```
>>> import re
>>> words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word23']
>>> regex = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(w) for w in words]))
>>> regex
re.compile('word1|word2|word23')
>>> list_of_str = ['some phrase with word1','another phrase','other phrase with word2']
>>> [phrase for phrase in list_of_str if not regex.search(phrase)]
['another phrase']
>>> [phrase for phrase in list_of_str if regex.search(phrase)]
['some phrase with word1', 'other phrase with word2']
>>>
```

Comment: Makes sense, but are you sure that regex is efficient ? I am pretty sure I came across other questions which mentioned regex was not efficient (slow) when you start doing this kind of thing for long lists.

Comment: A quick bench on the three suggested solutions (any/all, regexps and sets) give kederrac's solution as the fastest, then deceze's one, then juanpa's one far behing. But this is using only those small datasets, so take it with a grain of salt...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers it's going to depend on the nature of the data a lot, the relative frequency of the words actually appearing in the phrases

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga totally agree - as I clearly (well, possibly not clearly enough ?) mentionned, a serious benchmark would require real-life datasets and real-life usage patterns examples ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it in *sets*, you want sentences from that list where the set of search words and the set of words in the sentence are either disjoint or intersect.

E.g.:

```
set('some phrase with word1'.split()).isdisjoint({'word1', 'word2', 'word23'})
not set('some phrase with word1'.split()).isdisjoint({'word1', 'word2', 'word23'})
# or:
set('some phrase with word1'.split()) & {'word1', 'word2', 'word23'}
```

So:

```
search_terms = {'word1', 'word2', 'word23'}
list1 = [i for i in list_of_str if set(i.split()).isdisjoint(search_terms)]
list2 = [i for i in list_of_str if not set(i.split()).isdisjoint(search_terms)]
```

Comment: what if the splitting it is not so easy and you end up with words like 'word1\n' or 'word1,' ?

Comment: Then this algorithm may not be suitable.